# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'VausRestController' method

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, applicationcontext

I am trying to setup REST server that supports only 1 HTTP request.
I received the following exception:

```
2017/05/10 16:42:46.036 ERROR:  
 Failed starting server: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'VausRestController' method 
 public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.nds.ch.vge.vaus.restController.VausRestController$ErrorResponse> com.nds.ch.vge.vaus.restController.VausRestController.signature(com.nds.ch.vge.vaus.types.EcdsaSignature)
 to {[/authentication/signature],methods=[PUT]}: There is already 'vausRestController' bean method
 public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.nds.ch.vge.vaus.restController.VausRestController$ErrorResponse> com.nds.ch.vge.vaus.restController.VausRestController.signature(com.nds.ch.vge.vaus.types.EcdsaSignature) mapped.
```

The application context (relevant part):

```
<context:annotation-config />

<bean id="VausRestController" class="restController.VausRestController">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>
```

Code:

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@Controller
@RestController
public class VausRestController {


    @Resource(name="authenticationManager")
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value ="/authentication/signature", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> signature( @RequestBody final EcdsaSignature ecdsaSignature) {

        return ......
    }
```

Notice that I have only one `@RequestMapping`.
I also tried to change the spring versions in my pom.xml - didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this failure is that in the application context 'bean' I had capital letter `id="VausRestController"`

To fix, I used:

```
<bean id="vausRestController" class="restController.VausRestController">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Just a side note: why do you have the bean definition at all? Cause you enabled your context to be annotation driven which means that you don't have to specify the bean explicitly in your XML anymore. Besides that XML config is something that you usually don't wan't to do AND I'd personally move to constructor injection rather than field injection – see: http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/